# Understanding the tensorboard plots on a stable-baseline3's PPO

Tags: reinforcement-learning, tensorboard

So there are various plots that are provided when training a stable-baselines3's PPO model, so I thought you'd help me fill up the gaps with what is not quite clear to me:

- `rollout/ep_len_mean`: that would be the mean episode's length. What is the expected behavior?
- `rollout/ep_rew_mean`: the mean episode reward. Expected to increase over time
- `time/fps`: ?
- `train/approx_kl`: How different is $\pi_t$ compared to $\pi_{t+1}$. I *suppose* it should decrease over time as $\pi$ approaches the optimal policy. (Not sure though why it is the approximated value, and not the exact one)
- `train/clip_fraction`: some measurement to how the reward $r_t$ was clipped (as in trust regions). Should decrease over time as we're not stepping out of "boundaries" as much given a trained policy.
- `train/clip_range`: ?
- `train/entropy_loss`: *perhaps* it represents how random our actions are? not quite sure what to be expected here.
- `train/explained_variance`: I would say that this one represents how well we approximate the value function, so it should increase over time.
- `train/learning_rate`: the model's learning rate. *Presumably* will decrease over time, but perhaps it is not the default behavior
- `train/loss`: total $L_{CLIP}$ loss? should decrease over time
- `train/policy_gradient_loss`: ?
- `train/std`: ?
- `train/value_loss`: ?

Comment: Have you tried to read the relevant papers before running the algorithm? Are you familiar with Reinforcement Learning with function approximation in general? From your questions (e.g. what is value loss, policy gradient loss etc) it seems that you are not familiar with the basics of RL and Policy Gradient. I believe that you would benefit way more if you study this by yourself as even an answer as the one provided won't help you much. You can check https://spinningup.openai.com/en/latest/algorithms/ppo.html which has very nice and concise tutorials!You can check the intro material as well.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The explanation of all logged values can be found on the [documentation page of the `Logger` class](https://stable-baselines3.readthedocs.io/en/master/common/logger.html#logger):

##### eval/

All `eval/` values are computed by the `EvalCallback`.

- `mean_ep_length`: Mean episode length
- `mean_reward`: Mean episodic reward (during evaluation)
- `success_rate`: Mean success rate during evaluation (1.0 means 100% success), the environment info dict must contain an `is_success` key to compute that value

##### rollout/

- `ep_len_mean`: Mean episode length (averaged over 100 episodes)
- `ep_rew_mean`: Mean episodic training reward (averaged over 100 episodes), a `Monitor` wrapper is required to compute that value (automatically added by `make_vec_env`).
- `exploration_rate`: Current value of the exploration rate when using DQN, it corresponds to the fraction of actions taken randomly (epsilon of the "epsilon-greedy" exploration)
- `success_rate`: Mean success rate during training (averaged over 100 episodes), you must pass an extra argument to the `Monitor` wrapper to log that value (`info_keywords=("is_success",)`) and provide `info["is_success"]=True/False` on the final step of the episode

##### time/

- `episodes`: Total number of episodes
- `fps`: Number of frames per seconds (includes time taken by gradient update)
- `iterations`: Number of iterations (data collection + policy update for A2C/PPO)
- `time_elapsed`: Time in seconds since the beginning of training
- `total_timesteps`: Total number of timesteps (steps in the environments)

##### train/

- `actor_loss`: Current value for the actor loss for off-policy algorithms
- `approx_kl`: approximate mean KL divergence between old and new policy (for PPO), it is an estimation of how much changes happened in the update
- `clip_fraction`: mean fraction of surrogate loss that was clipped (above `clip_range` threshold) for PPO.
- `clip_range`: Current value of the clipping factor for the surrogate loss of PPO
- `critic_loss`: Current value for the critic function loss for off-policy algorithms, usually error between value function output and TD(0), temporal difference estimate
- `ent_coef`: Current value of the entropy coefficient (when using SAC)
- `ent_coef_loss`: Current value of the entropy coefficient loss (when using SAC)
- `entropy_loss`: Mean value of the entropy loss (negative of the average policy entropy)
- `explained_variance`: Fraction of the return variance explained by the value function, see https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/model_evaluation.html#explained-variance-score
  (ev=0 => might as well have predicted zero, ev=1 => perfect prediction, ev<0 => worse than just predicting zero)
- `learning_rate`: Current learning rate value
- `loss`: Current total loss value
- `n_updates`: Number of gradient updates applied so far
- `policy_gradient_loss`: Current value of the policy gradient loss (its value does not have much meaning)
- `value_loss`: Current value for the value function loss for on-policy algorithms, usually error between value function output and Monte-Carle estimate (or TD(lambda) estimate)
- `std`: Current standard deviation of the noise when using generalized State-Dependent Exploration (gSDE)